# Updating a SwiftUI TextEditor on font change

Tags: swiftui

So I have a TextEditor defined as follows:

```
HStack()
{
    TextEditor(text: $tvText)
        .font(.custom("AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold", size: CGFloat(MyUserSettings.shared.fontSize)))
        .autocapitalization(.sentences)
        .disableAutocorrection(true)
        .border(Color(UIColor(named: "DarkBrown")!), width: 1)
        .frame(height: 96 + 8)
```

And in my settings screen I allow the user to change the font size.  When the view loads it pulls the font size from MyUserSettings as seen above.  When the user goes to the settings screen and changes the font size, that new size gets saved to MyUserSettings.

Problem:
When the user returns to the main screen with the TextEditor the font size is not changed.  It is the initial size loaded from MyUserSettings.  I need to load the new size from MyUserSettings so the new font size is displayed.

Question:
How do I force redraw the TextEditor so it can pick up the new font size?

I am new to SwiftUI so I hope this makes sense.  In UIKit I would set the font size of the UITextView in viewWillAppear.  What is the approach in SwiftUI?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to observe it somehow using one of the SwiftUI Wrappers

Comment: Lol, ok.  Well, I am new to SwiftUI so I am not exactly sure what you mean.  Is there an article, book, video, example or something you can send me that I can look at?  I did see a couple articles about @ObservableObject, but it did not talk about my type of situation.

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Comment: They are talking about your kind of situation. That is what you need.

Comment: I have gone through those previously and I do not remember seeing anything about @ObservableObject, objectWillChange.send, refreshing a view or UIRepresentable.  So could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: That is what SwiftUI wrappers do, they reload the Views, that is their sole purpose. Some are sources of truth others are two way connections but they all reload the view when needed and share the new values. As you know `struct`s are immutable on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample

```
import SwiftUI
//Make your settings an ObservableObject
class MyUserSettings: ObservableObject{
    @Published var fontSize: CGFloat = 48
}
struct MyFontView: View{
    //Create the object in a parent view vs using a singleton
    @StateObject var userSettings: MyUserSettings = MyUserSettings()
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                //Mimic changing size
                Slider(value: $userSettings.fontSize, in: 12...100, label: {
                    Text("Font Size = \(userSettings.fontSize)")
                })
                NavigationLink("editor view", destination: {
                    ChangingFontView()
                })
            }
        }
        //Inject it into the environment so you can access anywhere in the navigation view
        .environmentObject(userSettings)
    }
}
struct ChangingFontView: View {
    //Access the environment object that will reload the view when there is a new value
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: MyUserSettings
    @State private var tvText: String = "tv Text"
    var body: some View {
        HStack()
        {
            TextEditor(text: $tvText)
            //Use the environment variable
                .font(.custom("AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold", size: CGFloat(userSettings.fontSize)))
                .autocapitalization(.sentences)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .border(Color.blue, width: 2)
            //SwiftUI does not react well to harcoded values
            //This is a key difference with UIKit
            //Let SwiftUI do most of the worl
                .frame(height: 96 + 8)
        }
    }
}

struct ChangingFontView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyFontView()
    }
}
```

I recommend you watch the SwiftUI videos from WWDC like [Demystifying SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) and all the other basic ones. It is different than UIKit nothing gets done without wrappers in SwiftUI these reload the view when there are updates.

Comment: Yes, I will definitely watch that video. I did look at your sample, thank you ,very helpful. I understand the flow, but one question. Does @environmentObject only go one way in the nav chain? My usage is opposite of what you posted. I have a main view with the TextEditor, and a settings view with the slider. If I reverse it and have the TextEditor screen navigate to the settings, I need to pull the value back. I will test it, but I don't think it works that way. I am incorrect on that assumption? Basically, my child needs to update the parent.

Comment: The StateObject is the source of truth. That needs to go in the uppermost view that the child views have in common. You inject the environment object from there. So they can all have access. The source of truth holds all the changes. If I answered your question please accept it.

Comment: Yes, you did, I get it.  Thank you, you have been most helpful!! I will definitely accept it.  I am also watching the WWDC video, that too is helpful as it explains some subtleties I was missing. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something simple using State and bindings. Something like this approach:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var tvText = "some text"
    @State var fonto = "AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold"
    @State var fontoSize: Double = 12.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 55) {
            Button(action: {
                fonto = "Source Sans Pro"
                fontoSize = 25.0
            }) { Text("Change font and size") }
            HStack {
                TextEditor(text: $tvText)
                    .font(.custom(fonto, size: CGFloat(fontoSize)))
                    .autocapitalization(.sentences)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .border(.blue)
                    .frame(height: 111)
            }
            MyUserSettings(fontoSize: $fontoSize)
        }
    }
}

struct MyUserSettings: View {
    @Binding var fontoSize: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $fontoSize, in: 0 ... 60, step: 1).padding()
    }
}
```